# CALC III: Vector Functions and Space Curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm a little confused on how to approach the question, I understand I take the derivative of the parameters, and then plug in the point. But, what do I do with the plane ?

Find the points of intersection, if any, of the tangent line to a curve $r(t)= <3t^2,t^3,-3t^4>$, $t$ a real number, at the point $(3,-1,-3)$ with the plane $x-y+z=-1$ ?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The curve $\gamma:\>t\mapsto {\bf r}(t)$ passes the point $P=(3,-1,3)$ at time $t=-1$. From ${\bf r}'(t)=(6t,3t^2,-12t^3)$ we obtain ${\bf r}'(-1)=(-6,3,12)$. This is the direction of the tangent to $\gamma$ at $P$. This tangent $\ell$ therefore has the parametric representation
$$\ell:\quad \tau\mapsto (3,-1,3)+\tau(-6,3,12)\qquad(-\infty<\tau<\infty)$$
(note that we need a new "time" parameter for $\ell$). Intersecting $\ell$ with the plane $x-y+z=-1$ leads to the equation
$$(3-6\tau)-(-1+3\tau)+(3+12\tau)=1$$
for $\tau$. It follows that $\ell$ hits the plane at the "eigenzeit" $\tau=-2$, and the point of intersection is $\ell(-2)=\ldots\ $.